# Efficient Alternative for .save() on existing Model.Document

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have some questions regarding .save on exiting document.

I am searching after a efficient solution for updating a document.

I heard about `.updateOne()` , but I feel unfamiliar to it, since I have to parseout the field, which should be updated and then parse out the values from the whole cached document.

`.save()` , saves all my work, but I am searching after a alternative, since the parallelsaveerror occurs, when I have many fast requests to save and I have to cache the document as a "mongoose document" (I do not want to fetch it before) , which uses a lot of ram.

Thx in advance!

```
Version:
mongoose: ^5.10.2,
nodejs: v14.15.5
mongodb: node driver on mongodb atlas
```

Answer (score 0):

**here is a bulkWrite operation from moongose**

```
let queryOperation = [];
      queryOperation.push({
          updateOne: {
            filter: hereGoesWhereCondition, //{_id: user._id}
            update: data, // object of fields to update
          }
        });
      const name = await model.bulkWrite(queryOperation); //model is the table in which you want to update
```

Comment: The point is, I do not want to parse out the fields to update manually. Is there any easier solution or any function, when I have two versions of the document. I can compare it and then it automatically provides me the fields to update?

Comment: I guess No, might be possible that someone come up with some trick

Comment: But there must be something, which the mongoose library does in the backend